# Wrong Data Coming from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I try to make student result management system. I face problem when I try to give position every student depend on their total obtain mark in exam. In my output I get 1st(obtain mark 448),2nd(obtain mark 444),3rd(obtain mark 445),4th(obtain mark 447), 15th(obtain mark 450),8th(obtain mark 449) But I don't find any problem in my code. It should be 1st(obtain mark 450),2nd(obtain mark 449)....
[image: Output Table]
[image: My Databse]

```
if (!function_exists('get_student_position')) {

function get_student_position($school_id, $academic_year_id, $class_id, $student_id, $section_id = null) {

    $condition = " academic_year_id = $academic_year_id ";
    $condition .= " AND school_id = $school_id";
    $condition .= " AND class_id = $class_id";
    $condition .= " AND student_id = $student_id";
    if($section_id){
        $condition .= " AND section_id = $section_id";
    }

   $ci = & get_instance();              
    $sql = "SELECT id, avg_grade_point, FIND_IN_SET( (avg_grade_point+total_obtain_mark), 
            ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( (avg_grade_point+total_obtain_mark) ORDER BY avg_grade_point DESC )
            FROM final_results ) ) AS rank 
            FROM final_results 
            WHERE $condition";


    $result =  $ci->db->query($sql)->row(); 

    $rank = '';
    if(!empty($result)){
        $rank = $result->rank;
    }

    if($rank == 1){
        return $rank.'st';
    }elseif($rank == 2){
       return $rank.'nd'; 
    }elseif($rank == 3){
       return $rank.'rd'; 
    }elseif($rank > 3 ){
        return $rank.'th';         
    }else{
        return '--'; 
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: try to order by total_obtain_mark

Comment: And please... never concatenate SQL values.. use binding instead.